# The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over. Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a Cart model and Cartserializers. I am trying to do that is if cart defects exist in the cart and then update the cart by increasing the quantity of cart. I tried a lot to do this. But it raises an error every time this time is ***The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over***.

Here is my code :)

***views.py****

```
class CartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active and user.is_superuser or user.is_Customer:
                    return Cart.objects.all()
                raise PermissionDenied()
            raise PermissionDenied()
        raise PermissionDenied()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['date_created', 'user']
    @action(detail=False)
    def count(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        count = queryset.count()
        content = {'count': count}
        return Response(content)
        
    def create(validated_data, get):
        quantity, created = Cart.objects.update_or_create(
            user = validated_data.get('user', None),
            defects=validated_data.get('defects', None),
            defaults={'quantity': validated_data.get('quantity' + str(1), None)})
        return quantity
        if quantity is created.create:
            return Response ({
                'status' : True,
                "detail" : "created"
            })
        if quantity is created.update:
            return Response ({
                'status' : True,
                "detail" : "updated"
            })
```

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import User, SubCategory

# Create your models here.

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name="carts", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    service = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory',null=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    defects = models.ForeignKey('Defects',null=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
 
    price = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

***serializers.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id','url', 'user', 'service', 'defects', 'date_created', 'quantity' , 'price', 'total']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your get_queryset() method must return a queryset!